# BDC: cannot logon with credentials obtained from secure store provider

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, bcs

Hmm..

When I manually create a new contentsource, point it to the single sql database-bcs everything works OK (no probs) (via Central Admin) but...

When i try the *same* via a powershell script I get "BDC: cannot logon with credentials obtained from secure store provider"

So... i remember vaguely someting about creating the contentsource in PWS, so the thing underneath delivers me the above error, so there is a bug in the PWS script beneath: (although it does create the new contentsource, the bcs source is checked in the gui and it starts the full crawl AND... this works on another server flawlessly...) :

```
function loadContentSource
{
    # remove the current contentsource
    $sa = Get-SpEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
    Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $sa -Identity $contentsourceName -Confirm:$false
    # create the new contentsource
    $proxyGroup = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup -default
    New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $sa -Name $contentsourceName -Type Business -LOBSystemSet $LobSystems -BDCApplicationProxyGroup $proxyGroup
    # start a full crawl
    $contentsource = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $sa -Identity $contentsourceName
    $contentsource.StartFullCrawl()
}
```

So "visually" the above gives me the same result in Central Admin but apparently there is something under the cover different than doing it manually and im pretty positive it is in the line "New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource" but hmm wait maybe its Get-SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup

Comment: $LobSystems  how this is formed?

Comment: $LobSystems = @("ABC", "ABC") { so it DOES place the checkmark in the Central Admin content source BDC settings)

Comment: Check ABC is the same for  @("LOBSystemName","LOBSystemInstanceName")

Comment: When I check the exported bdcm file it shows me ABC for the LobSystemInstanceName and Lobystem type database and name= ABC, so from that i assume this to be correct?